# Java - Splitting MultiSheet Excel into separate Excels each containing single sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Say I have an Excel (Test.xlsx) having multiple sheets in it (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, etc.) I want to split all these sheets present in 1 excels to separate excels using Java.

Input - Test.xlsx(having Sht1, Sht2, Sht3 ..)

Output - Sht1.xlsx , Sht2.xlsx, Sht3.xlsx ...

I tried doing the same using apache poi but could not achieve :( Need to do it programmatically using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Copying sheets seems to be tricky, see. e.g. https://robsnotebook.com/copy-a-sheet-to-a-different-workbook-in-apache-poi/

How about making copies of the original workbook and then deleting all sheets except one? This should be possible to achieve with Apache POI.